# Memcached - i installed it on centOS and have it running. Will it auto run when i reboot?

Tags: linux, centos, memcached, memcache

I did this:

> sudo yum install memcached

then

```
sudo pecl install memcache
```

then I restarted memcache (which actually only started it) with this:

> sudo /sbin/service memcached restart

i have no idea if it will start when I reboot. How do i set that up?

also is there any way to set a password on memcache? I've limited it to 127.0.0.1  by editing /etc/sysconfig/memcached

and adding this line

```
OPTIONS="-l 127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set memcached (or most other services with an init script) to start at boot with a command such as:

```
chkconfig memcached on
```

Answer (score -1):

[man chkconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig)

In that manpage, there are options to list the current status and to enable it at runtime.